# How do I prevent my window from being docked by virtual keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, vb6, on-screen-keyboard, window-messages

When I tap into a textbox in my application, the Microsoft on-screen keyboard appears and shrinks my application window so that my app only occupies 60% of the screen, and the on-screen keyboard occupies the remaining screen space.

How could I intercept this behaviour?

So far I have not found a way to stop the on-screen keyboard from doing it. I wish it would simply show up but not resize my app window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to prevent the on-screen keyboard from doing that:

The following solution surely works on Windows 11, and on *some* versions of Windows 10, it works, too. On some versions of Windows 10, this gear icon or this keyboard size / location option is not offered.

-->

Click the gear, then icon which shows the on-screen keyboard floating on the screen instead of the icon which shows the on-screen keyboard docked on the bottom.

Or (in a newer version of Windows 11) click the icon in the top right corner of the keyboard:

[image]